# $|X|\in\mathcal{L}^p\Leftrightarrow X\in\mathcal{L}^p\hspace{0.3cm}\forall p>1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, lp-spaces, expected-value

Given a probability space $\left(\Omega\text{, }\mathcal{F}\text{, }\mathbb{P}\right)$ and a random variable $X$ defined on it, I know that it holds true that $|X|\in\mathcal{L}^1 \Leftrightarrow X\in\mathcal{L}^1$.
Does it hold true that $|X|\in\mathcal{L}^p \Leftrightarrow X\in\mathcal{L}^p\hspace{0.3cm}\forall p>1$ as well?

Comment: If you change $|X|^{p}$ with $|X|$, then it is true.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was just a typo of mine. Is there some way to prove it is true also for $p>1$? @DarthLubinus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$|X| \in \mathcal{L}^p \iff \int ||X||^p < \infty \iff \int|X|^p < \infty \iff X \in \mathcal{L}^p$$

Answer (score 1):

I understand that

$$\mathcal{L}^{p}=\{ X\colon \Omega\to \mathbb{R}\colon X\text{ is measurable and } E(|X|^{p})<\infty \}.$$

If $X\in \mathcal{L}^{p}$, we have by definition that $E(|X|^{p})=\int_{\Omega}|X|^{p}<\infty$, so $|X|\in \mathcal{L}^{p}$. Conversely, if $|X|\in \mathcal{L}^{p}$, then by definition $E(|X|^{p})<\infty$, so $X\in \mathcal{L}^{p}$.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way, but I could be wrong. Thanks anyway for your help @DarthLubinus

Comment: @Strictly_increasing what do you mean it's not the right way?  It is the definition

Comment: $|X|\in\mathcal{L}^p\Leftrightarrow E(||X||^{p})<\infty $, right? So, do you mean that $E\{||X||^p\}=E\{|X|^p\}$? It sounds strange to me since on my textbook for $p=1$ I have a proof of the fact that $X\in\mathcal{L}\Leftrightarrow|X|\in\mathcal{L}$ which is a bit less trivial than simple application of the definition and which relies on the fact that $X=X^+-X^-$ and $|X|=X^++X^-$ @Shashi

Comment: @Strictly_increasing I don't get it, maybe you should ask yourself what it means $|X|\in L^p$ and $X\in L^p$. You'll see that they are equivalent.

Comment: You say that they are equivalent since $||X||$=$|X|$, don't you? Since by definition a random variable is $\mathcal{L}$-integrable if the expected value of its absolute value is less than $\infty$. Take $X=|X|$ and you have $E\{||X||\}<\infty$ @Shashi

Comment: @Strictly_increasing what is $|\cdot|$ and what is $\|\cdot\|$ here? Euclidean metric, absolute value, norm on $L^p$?

Comment: Simply a double absolute value. Sorry for not specifying @Shashi

Comment: @Strictly_increasing oh yes then I see it, I'd say yes!

Comment: Ok, thank you and sorry for the mess @Shashi